# Фрагменты в Андроид

Tags: android, activity, android-fragment

Android работа с Fragment.

Создаю и добавляю фрагменты в программно:

```
fragmenttransaction = fragmentmanager.beginTransaction();
        fragmenttransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_up, R.anim.slide_down);

        if (fragmentmanager.findFragmentByTag(LoginFragment.TAG) != null) {
            fragmenttransaction.remove(fragment_login);
        }
        if (fragmentmanager.findFragmentByTag(RegistrationFragment.TAG) == null) {
            fragmenttransaction.add(R.id.layout_login_window, fragment_registration, RegistrationFragment.TAG);
        }
        fragmenttransaction.commit();
```

Главный класс Активити унаследован от AppCompatActivity.

Каким образом мне перехватить onCreateView у добавляемого фрагмента, чтобы понять что я могу инициализировать View относящиеся фрагменту?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Методы жизненного цмкла будут вызваны автоматически после `fragmenttransaction.commit();`

Всё, что вам нужно - в вашем классе фрагмента их переопределить:

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment
{
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        System.out.println("onCreateView called");
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! К View элементам обращаться через класс фрагмента? К примеру, чтобы в фрагменте TextView изменить текст.

Comment: Да. Там всё не слишком просто, но вполне возможно в приведённом в ответе методе инициализировать поля класса, содержащие элементы разметки фрагмента и изменять их, вызывая созданные методы фрагмента. Фрагмент можно получить из fragmentmanager

Comment: Ещё можно через `LocalBroadcastManager` посылать `Intent`-ы фрагменту.

Comment: Либо пользовать какую-либо либу для пересылки сообщений. Сам не юзал, но слышал про `EventBus` и `Otto`

Comment: Все, разобрался! Спасибо большое!